# Why can C functions not return arrays?

Tags: c, arrays

In C, a `struct` (record data structure) can be the return type of a function, but an array cannot be. What design characteristics of the C Language cause arrays to be an exception?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please show two short code snippets - one that compiles, illustrating the return of a structure, and another one that does not compile, illustrating the non-working return of an array.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I think this question is easily understood without code snippets.

Comment: This is literally a homework question, directly copied and pasted. You should show us that you did at least a little bit of research before having us write your homework.

Answer (score 10):

A naked array type in C language is not copyable for primarily historical reasons. For this reason it is not possible to initialize arrays with arrays, assign arrays to arrays, pass arrays by value as parameters or return arrays from functions. (Initialization context has a notable exception of `char s[6] = "Hello";`.)

It is still possible to do all the above if the array is wrapped in struct type, which demonstrates that the limitation is purely declarative in nature. There's no compelling technical reason for it.

C language inherited its approach to array implementation from its historical predecessors - B and BCPL languages. In B/BCPL arrays were openly implemented as pointers, meaning that an attempt to assign one array to another actually represented assignment of pointers. C language followed a different approach. In C arrays are not pointers, but the interface specification of C arrays is kept superficially compatible with that of B/BCPL. Arrays in C still "pretend" to be pointers in most contexts. This is one reason they are not immediately copyable.

Comment: Would there be a problem to allow it nowadays? I think both, returning arrays and assigning to them, wouldn't be ambiguous in any situation, and wouldn't change the semantics of existing valid code. And, as you said, it's not harder to implement as returning/assigning structures. So maybe there's another, non-historic reason?

Comment: (and +1 of course, to back up the historic background, maybe add a link: http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html; the chapter "Embryonic C" explains the changes from BCPL regarding arrays)

Comment: @mafso: Yes, it doesn't look like there wouldn't be any ambiguity if C simply allowed copying of arrays if the source and destination has exactly the same array type. The only context that is already "taken" is function parameter declarations: a declaration that looks like an array passed "by value" actually decays to pointer parameter.

Comment: @AndreyT: It doesn't "decay" (that's the term commonly used for the conversion of an array expression to a pointer to its first element). It's "adjusted", meaning that the type is changed at compile time. `void func(int arr[])` really *means* `void func(int *arr)`.

Answer (score 7):

Most obviously, the "lack" is that C doesn't permit a function to return a result of an array type. This is stated explicitly in the language standard.

Array types are, in a sense, second-class citizens in C. In most contexts, an expression of array type is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. The exceptions are when the array expression is the operand of `sizeof` (which yields the size of the array), when it's the operand of unary `&` (which yields the address of the array), and when it's a string literal in an initializer used to initialize an array object.

This absolutely *does not* mean that arrays are "really" pointers; they're not. You'll see people claiming that they are. They're wrong.

Functions return values. You can have a value of a structure type; that value consists of the values of its members. C permits assignment, parameter passing, and function results of structure type. All these manipulate array values (they deal with them by value, not by reference).

The same is not true for arrays. The rules I mentioned above imply that you can't construct an expression whose *value* is of an array type. There are array values (consisting of the values of all the array's elements), but such values are difficult or impossible to manipulate directly.

The way C code usually manipulates arrays is by using pointers to individual elements.

It probably wouldn't have been too difficult to have designed C so that *fixed-size* arrays can be treated as values, with assignment, parameter passing, and so forth. But then you'd run into problems where `int[10]` and `int[11]` are two distinct and incompatible types. Most C code that deals with arrays needs to handle arrays whose size is determined at run time. For example, the string functions in `<string.h>` deal with arrays of characters of any arbitrary length. They do so by using pointers to the elements of the arrays. You couldn't very well have distinct functions for 1-element, 2-element, 3-element, and so forth, arrays.

You can do the equivalent of returning an array value from a function, but it's unfortunately awkward. You can return a structure containing the array -- but then the size of the array has to be fixed at compile time. You can return a pointer to (the first element of) the array -- but then you have to deal with allocating and deallocating memory to hold the array. You can have the caller pass in a pointer to an array -- but that places the burden of memory management on the caller. And so forth.

Yes, it's all a bit of a mess. But dealing with arrays that can vary in size is genuinely difficult. C gives you all the tools you need to do it, but leaves a lot of the detailed management to you, the programmer. (Other languages provide arrays as first-class types. Many of those languages have compilers or interpreters written in C.)

Suggested reading: Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: No doubt there was a good reason for the downvote. I'd be interested in knowing what it was.

Comment: Someone had some karma to burn; *all* answers were downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

The characteristic is that in the small and speedy C language you don't want the equivalent of large `memcpy` operations when returning. If you *badly need* arrays returned, make them a member of a `struct`, and voila, array return in C. Sort of, starting with C89 :-)

Or use a `memcpy` yourself when and where you need it.

Comment: @mafso: was structure return possible in K&R C (pre C89)? I vaguely remember it wasn't.

Comment: Afaik it wasn't. Don't know about assignment, though. So maybe what you wrote was the reason why it wasn't allowed in K&R C and it wasn't added for arrays in C89, because passing them to a function (by value) was impossible without breaking most of existing code and not allowing it would be somewhat inconsistent (you can return them but not pass them). And after all, this feature wasn't really useful, I think.

Comment: @mafso I just looked it up in *The C Programming Language, 1st Ed.*, page 121: "This implies that structures may not be assigned to or copied as a unit, and that they can not be passed to or returned from functions. (These restrictions will be removed in forthcoming versions.)"

Answer (score -3):

While the array can't be returned from a C function, a pointer to the array may. For code example of how to do what you're looking for, visit the site:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_return_arrays_from_function.htm

Comment: Sorry Anthony, I am afraid that you haven't read the question.